# Consult email from the database and send

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to send an email with this function, if I write the email statically, it works correctly, but when trying to query it from the database, the **$email_user** variable does not get the value of the sql query. What am I doing wrong ?

Model

```
public function send(){

        $this->db->select('email_user');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('id_user= "8" ');
        $email_user = $this->db->get()->row();

        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to($email_user);
        $this->email->subject('example');
        $this->email->message('Hello World');
        $this->email->send();

}
```

Comment: how do you fetch the `id_user` value from your database? Please show the relevant code...

Comment: It's just an example to see if the variable  $email_user gets mail from the sql query XD

Comment: yes, I know and it works you say, correct? now we need to see how you get id_user from db, because there is the error, most likely

Comment: I'm just writing it manually ..... XD

Comment: I think you did not understand what I wrote

Comment: you write in your question "trying to query it from the database, the $email_user variable does not get the value of the sql query." but you don't show how you are doing it...

Comment: I think it's pretty clear, I'm writing the sql query data manually, the result of that should be taken by the $ email_user variable, but it's not doing it, because if I did, the mail would be sent correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157324/discussion-between-vickel-and-kvothe-0077).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set your email config and also try like below with db

```
public function send(){

    $id = '8';

    $this->db->where('id_user', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    $row = $query->row();

    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '****',
        'smtp_pass' => '****',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Admin');
    $this->email->to($row->email_user);
    $this->email->subject('example');
    $this->email->message('Hello World');
    $this->email->send();

}
```

Comment: thank you for replying, but still, do not send the email

Comment: Are you using localhost. You may need to set up your local host send mail settings.

Comment: If I use localhost, but it is already configured, as I mentioned before, if it sends the email, if it is static